# Como passar property-bind para o router-outlet em angular 2

Tags: angular

Olá, pessoal. Eu sou novato aprendendo angular 2 e tenho essa dúvida do título.
Meu router-outlet: `<router-outlet [busca]="termo"></router-outlet>` com esse property-bind e me retorna esse erro no console:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'busca' since it isn't a known property of 'router-outlet'.

Obrigado de antemão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se não me engano, não é possível passar um bind para `router-outlet,` ele atua como somente um seletor que o *Angular* dinamicamente preenche com o componente desejado baseado no atual estado da rota. Para entender melhor, o que você gostaria com esse *bind*? Jogar informações dinamicamente aos componentes? Se sim, é mais interessante você trabalhar com parâmetros via rota ou mesmo `Input` nos seus componentes

Comment: Exatamente! Eu preciso mandar informações dinamicamente para um componente em específico. O interessante é que se eu passar para um componente qualquer ele funciona normalmente, mas para o router-outlet não. Eu estou aprendendo, sabe? Estou tentando seguir as video-aulas, porém fazendo minhas próprias modificações. Aprendi a mudar as rotas usando o router-outlet, se você puder me ajudar a fazer de alguma outra forma que me permitisse passar binds para os componentes, eu agradeceria muito!

Answer (score 2):

Eu tbm acho que não tem como fazer isso... se vc quer passar informações de um componente para outro talvez seja melhor criar um shared service